# printf debugging in SML

Tags: java, python, debugging, logging, sml

Is there a "nice" logging/debugging library for SML out there? I'm debugging some SML code that's intended to mirror some Java code. I'm interested in having both programs print out intermediate values during computation. I've found [this](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/leunga/sml-software.htm) library to get something resembling C/Java's `printf()`, which is a big help. There are plenty of good logging libraries out there for Java, so there shouldn't be any issue there.

However, adding print statements to SML adds a ridiculous number of lines of code and generally looks ugly and awful. Is there a nice way to do this? Maybe even something like Python's decorators?

Here's an example of what I'm referring to. With logging:

```
fun execute (points : Point.t list,
             nClusters : int,
             threshold : real,
             randomPtr : Random.rand,
             debug : bool) =
    let
        (* helper function for debugging *)
        fun printIterationInfo (index, points) =
            print(genericDebugFmt "\nLoop iteration index: " 
                                  index 
                                  "\npoints: " 
                                  (map Point.featuresRepr points))                  
        val initialClusters = initializeClusters(points, nClusters, randomPtr, debug)
        val _ = if debug then
                    printIterationInfo (~1, initialClusters)
                else ()
        fun loop (10, clusterCenters) = 
            if debug then
                (printIterationInfo (10, clusterCenters);
                clusterCenters)
            else
                clusterCenters
          | loop (index, clusterCenters) = 
            (* wow, adding logging is cumbersome... *)
            let
                val ans = work(points, clusterCenters, debug)
            in
                if debug then
                    (printIterationInfo (index, ans);
                     loop (index + 1, ans))
                else 
                    loop(index + 1, ans)        
            end
    in
        loop (0, initialClusters)
    end
end
```

Without logging:

```
fun execute (points : Point.t list,
             nClusters : int,
             threshold : real,
             randomPtr : Random.rand,
             debug : bool) =
    let
        val initialClusters = initializeClusters(points, nClusters, randomPtr, debug)

        fun loop (10, clusterCenters) = clusterCenters
          | loop (index, clusterCenters) = 
            loop(index + 1, ans)        
    in
        loop (0, initialClusters)
    end
end
```

Comment: set up the log level to debug and use that level.

Comment: What log level are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

SML has printf: http://mlton.org/Printf

It might make some print statements nicer looking, but it doesn't solve the verbosity of adding print-debugging everywhere in the program.

If you want less invasive debugging functions, try and do something like Haskell's trace:

```
fun trace msg f = (print msg; f ())
```

And instead of

```
fun foo x = 2 + x
```

You do

```
fun foo x = trace "Hmm" (fn _ => 2 + x)
```

Admittedly, the extra anonymous function is not very nice, but it is necessary if we want the effect of `print "Hmm"` to happen before the expression `2 + x` potentially crashes.

Now, if you want your debug flag, you can embed this check into the trace function instead:

```
fun trace msg thunk = (if debug then print msg else (); thunk ())
```

...where `debug` is defined previously.